# Wkwebkitview iOS 17 Page break

Tags: uikit, wkwebview, wkhtmltopdf, ios17

While printing the page using WkWebkit
the line is slashed into two pieces and printed on different pages .
The issue is observed only on iOS 17

I had tried page-break but I didn't work
Could any one sort out the issue.....